# Update build properties on page refresh

Tags: python, continuous-integration, twisted, buildbot

I'm trying to set up behavior, if new file appeared in folder, Buildbot updates choices in it's web GUI(e.g. on page refresh)

scheduler section in master.cfg looks as follows:

`c['schedulers'].append(
    ForceScheduler(name = name, builderNames = builderNames
        properties=[
        ChoiceStringParameter(name="version", 
            choices = os.listdir(r"\path\to\folder"),
            label="Version of validator")
    ]))`

The problem with code, that buildbot doesn't pull updates after page reload.
Please, share any advice how this behavior can be achived

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my case solution  was overwrite getChoices() method of ChoiceStringParameter class, which should return list through function e.g. os.listdir(path). then buildForceContextForField function from web\builder.py calls this method and render it's result on webtemplate.